# Multiprocessing in a pipeline done right

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I'd like to know how multiprocessing is done right. Assuming I have a list `[1,2,3,4,5]` generated by function `f1` which is written to a `Queue` (left green circle). Now I start two processes pulling from that queue (by executing `f2` in the processes). They process the data, say: doubling the value, and write it to the second queue. Now, function `f3` reads this data and prints it out.

[image: layout of the data flow]

Inside the functions there is a kind of a loop, trying to read from the queue forever. How do I stop this process?

**Idea 1**

`f1` does not only send the list, but also a `None` object or a custon object, `class PipelineTerminator: pass` or some such which is just being propagated all the way down. `f3` now waits for `None` to come, when it's there, it breaks out of the loop. Problem: it's possible that one of the two `f2`s  reads and propagates the `None` while the other one it still processing a number. Then the last value is lost.

**Idea 2**

`f3` is `f1`. So the function `f1` generates the data and the pipes, spawns the processes with `f2` and feeds all data. After spawning and feeding, it listens on the second pipe, simply counting and processing the received objects. Because it knows how much data fed, it can terminate the processes executing `f2`. But if the target is to set up a processing pipeline, the different steps should be separable. So `f1`, `f2` and `f3` are different elements of a pipeline, and the expensive steps are done in parallel.

**Idea 3**

[image: pipeline idea 3]

Each piece of the pipeline is a function, this function spawns processes as it likes to and is responsible to manage them. It knows, how much data came in and how much data has been returned (with `yield` maybe). So it's safe to propagate a `None` object.

```
setup child processes 

execute thread one and two and wait until both finished

thread 1:
    while True:
        pull from input queue
        if None: break and set finished_flag
        else: push to queue1 and increment counter1

thread 2:
    while True:
        pull from queue2
        increment counter2
        yield result
        if counter1 == counter2 and finished_flag: break

when both threads finished: kill process pool and return.
```

(Instead of using threads, maybe one can think of a smarter solution.)

**So ...**

I have implemented a solution following idea 2, feeding and waiting for the results to arrive, but it was not really a pipeline with independent functions plugged together. It worked for the task I had to manage, but was hard to maintain.

I'd like to hear from you now how you implement pipelines (easy in one process with generator functions and so on, but with multiple processes?) and manage them usually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What would be wrong with using idea 1, but with each worker process (f2) putting a custom object with its identifier when it is done? Then f3, would just terminate that worker, until there was no worker process left.

Also, new in Python 3.2 is the concurrent.futures package on the standard library, that should do what you are trying to in the "right way" (tm) -
http://docs.python.org/dev/library/concurrent.futures.html

Maybe it is possible to find a backport of concurrent.futures to Python 2.x series.

Comment: But how should workers in `f2` *know* that it's the last one? `f1` needs to know how many workers there are and send that number of custom objects. Done like that, it's guaranteed that every worker gets this notification. That is clearly possible, but then I cannot "just plug the functions", I need to know how many workers there are in each step. That's why i like idea 3. And thank you for the `concurrent` stuff, that's new to me and I'll dig into it.

Comment: Since the "stop working" custom object is sent by "F1" it can include the total number of "f2" worker processes. If these just pass the "stop working" object to "f3" it gets to know the total number of workers. More information could be sent this way - so one important thing is to have a "control layer" at least in "f3" (but possibly also in "f1") which will just worry about this and just pass down any non "message" objects on the queue for being actually processed.

Answer (score 12):

With [MPipe](http://vmlaker.github.io/mpipe) module, simply do this:

```
from mpipe import OrderedStage, Pipeline

def f1(value):
    return value * 2

def f2(value):
    print(value)

s1 = OrderedStage(f1, size=2)
s2 = OrderedStage(f2)
p = Pipeline(s1.link(s2))

for task in 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, None:
    p.put(task)
```

The above runs *4 processes*:

- *two* for the first stage (function *f1*)
- *one* for the second stage (function *f2*)
- and *one* more for the main program that feeds the pipeline.

The [MPipe cookbook](http://vmlaker.github.io/mpipe/cookbook.html#operate-the-pipeline) offers some explanation of how processes are shut down internally using `None` as the last task.

To run the code, install MPipe:

```
virtualenv venv
venv/bin/pip install mpipe
venv/bin/python prog.py
```

Output:

```
2
4
6
8
10
```

Comment: Looks good, at least the introductory example! Nice logo, by the way.

Answer (score 2):

For Idea 1, how about:

```
import multiprocessing as mp

sentinel=None

def f2(inq,outq):
    while True:
        val=inq.get()
        if val is sentinel:
            break
        outq.put(val*2)

def f3(outq):
    while True:
        val=outq.get()
        if val is sentinel:
            break
        print(val)

def f1():
    num_workers=2
    inq=mp.Queue()
    outq=mp.Queue()
    for i in range(5):
        inq.put(i)
    for i in range(num_workers):        
        inq.put(sentinel)
    workers=[mp.Process(target=f2,args=(inq,outq)) for i in range(2)]
    printer=mp.Process(target=f3,args=(outq,))
    for w in workers:
        w.start()
    printer.start()
    for w in workers:
        w.join()
    outq.put(sentinel)
    printer.join()

if __name__=='__main__':
    f1()
```

The only difference from the description of Idea 1 is that `f2` breaks out of the `while-loop` when it receives the sentinel (thus terminating itself). `f1` blocks until the workers are done (using `w.join()`) and then sends `f3` the sentinel (signaling that it break out of its `while-loop`).

Comment: Thank you, that's similar to the approach I ended up implementing, but  your version is very readable. What I don't like is the fact that every component of the pipeline needs to know something about the pipeline, like in this case: `printer` needs to know the number of workers in the previous step and so on. That's why I thought about encapsulating this and give *every* step in the pipeline *exactly one* input and one output and the branching and merging takes place in each step.

Comment: That's a good point. You can make `f3` independent of `num_workers` but letting `f1` send the sentinel after the `workers` are done. I've edited the post to show what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

I use `concurent.futures` and three pools, which are connected together via `future.add_done_callback`. Then I wait for the whole process to end by calling `shutdown` on each pool.

```
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
import time
import random


def worker1(arg):
    time.sleep(random.random())
    return arg


def pipe12(future):
    pool2.submit(worker2, future.result()).add_done_callback(pipe23)


def worker2(arg):
    time.sleep(random.random())
    return arg


def pipe23(future):
    pool3.submit(worker3, future.result()).add_done_callback(spout)


def worker3(arg):
    time.sleep(random.random())
    return arg


def spout(future):
    print(future.result())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    __spec__ = None  # Fix multiprocessing in Spyder's IPython
    pool1 = ProcessPoolExecutor(2)
    pool2 = ProcessPoolExecutor(2)
    pool3 = ProcessPoolExecutor(2)
    for i in range(10):
        pool1.submit(worker1, i).add_done_callback(pipe12)
    pool1.shutdown()
    pool2.shutdown()
    pool3.shutdown()
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do exactly that is using semaphores.

**F1**

F1 is populating your 'Queue' with the data you want to process. End the end of this push, you put n 'Stop' keywords in your queue. n = 2 for your example, but usually the number of involved workers.
Code would look like:

```
for n in no_of_processes:
    tasks.put('Stop')
```

**F2**

F2 is pulling from the provided queue by a `get`-command. The element is taken from the queue and deleted in the queue. Now, you can put the pop into a loop while paying attention to the stop signal:

```
for elem in iter(tasks.get, 'STOP'):
   do something
```

**F3**

This one is a bit tricky. You could generate a semaphore in F2 that acts as a signal to F3. But you do not know when this signal arrives and you may loose data. However, F3 pulls the data the same way as F2 and you could put that into a `try... except`-statement.
`queue.get` raises an `queue.Empty`when there are no elements in the queue. So your pull in F3 would look like:

```
while control:
    try:
        results.get()
    except queue.Empty:
        control = False
```

With `tasks` and `results` being queues. So you do not need anything which is not already included in Python.

Answer (score 0):

[Pypeline](https://github.com/cgarciae/pypeln) does this for you. You can even choose between using Processes, Threads or async Tasks. What you want is just e.g. using Processes:

```
import pypeln as pl

data = some_iterable()
data = pl.process.map(f2, data, workers = 3)
data = list(data)
```

You can do more complex stuff

```
import pypeln as pl

data = some_iterable()
data = pl.process.map(f2, data, workers = 3)
data = pl.process.filter(f3, data, workers = 1)
data = pl.process.flat_map(f4, data, workers = 5)
data = list(data)
```

Comment: Why you don't use `concurrent` module? Does it lack some features?

Comment: @Winand due to similarities between the `multiprocessing.Process` and `threading.Thread` classes the code was easier to maintain if I just used these lower level APIs.