# How to set up a pipeline using Queues in multiprocessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing

Here's my code, it's supposed to do something very similar to what [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8277715/multiprocessing-in-a-pipeline-done-right) is trying to do, in particular this diagram is relavent: [image: Process Diagram]
with f1 = produce, f2 = f3 = worker, f4 = consumer.

I haven't yet tried to takle the problem of ending everything nicely, that's not what this question is about.  I'm getting the error "RuntimeError: Queue objects should only be shared between processes through inheritance"
And I'm not sure what to do to fix it.  I just want to pass the queues into functions like Go's channels, really.  Here is the code.

```
import multiprocessing


def produce(n, queue):
    for i in xrange(n):
        queue.put(i)

def worker(in_queue, out_queue):
    for i in iter( in_queue.get, None):
        out_queue.put(i*i)

def consumer(queue):
    ans = []
    for i in iter( queue.get, None):
        ans.append(i)
    return ans


def main(n):
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(4)
    in_queue = multiprocessing.Queue()
    out_queue = multiprocessing.Queue()

    pool.apply_async(produce, (n, in_queue))
    for i in range(2):
        pool.apply_async(worker, (in_queue, out_queue))
    result = consumer(out_queue)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    return result

main(200)
```

How would I go about fixing it?

Is there an easier way to do it?

I have tried `Pool.map`, but I'd like to get this working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `multiprocessing.Pool` already sets up the necessary IPC mechanisms to allow you to submit jobs to its workers after it has been started, but you can't pass ist a Queue or similar later as an argument. That's why your code doesn't work. At the time a subprocess is started, it aleady has to know how to communicate with its parent.

So if you need to set up your own Queues, you should use `multiprocessing.Process` directly. Also, what you're writing are typical workers, which wait in a loop for new jobs and process them. Running such a worker on a pool of workers is not something you want to do.

This way your code would work:

```
import multiprocessing


def produce(n, queue):
    for i in xrange(n):
        queue.put(i)

def worker(in_queue, out_queue):
    for i in iter( in_queue.get, None):
        out_queue.put(i*i)

def consumer(queue):
    ans = []
    for i in iter( queue.get, None):
        print(i)
        ans.append(i)
    return ans


def main(n):
    in_queue = multiprocessing.Queue()
    out_queue = multiprocessing.Queue()
    producer = multiprocessing.Process(target=produce, args=(n, in_queue))
    for i in range(2):
        w = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker, args=(in_queue, out_queue))
        w.start()
    producer.start()
    res = consumer(out_queue)

main(200)
```

I've added a print statement in your `consumer` to show that there is something happening. The `consumer` function just never terminates, because the code where you reading from the queues waits for a terminating `None` which never comes because neither workers nor producer ever put one into the queues...

Comment: Ah, so it was mixing pools and queues that caused the error, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Using `multiprocessing.Manager` it is possible to the share queues across pooled processes. I have updated OP's code to work with `pool.apply_async` method. For that, I have used `None` to indicate task completion in process methods and added code to wait for the completion of async calls in the main method.

```
import multiprocessing

def produce(n, queue):
    for i in xrange(n):
        queue.put(i)
    # None indicates termination / completion
    queue.put(None)

def worker(in_queue, out_queue):
    while True:
        i = in_queue.get()
        if i is None:
            # Put the None back for other workers listening to the queue to see
            in_queue.put(None)
            out_queue.put(None)
            return
        out_queue.put(i*i)

def consumer(queue):
    ans = []
    while True:
        i = queue.get()
        if i is None:
            queue.put(None)
            return ans
        ans.append(i)

def main(n):
    manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
    in_queue = manager.Queue()
    out_queue = manager.Queue()

    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(4)

    async_results = []
    ar = pool.apply_async(produce, (n, in_queue))
    async_results.append(ar)
    for i in range(2):
        ar = pool.apply_async(worker, (in_queue, out_queue))
        async_results.append(ar)
    ar = pool.apply_async(consumer, (out_queue,))
    async_results.append(ar)

    for ar in async_results:
        ar.wait()

    result = async_results[len(async_results)-1].get()
    print(result)

    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    return result

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(200)
```