# Is there an easy way to have "checkpoints" in an extended python script?

Tags: python, architecture

To preface my question let me give a bit of context: I'm currently working on a data pipeline that has a number of different steps. Each step can go wrong and many take some time (not a huge amount, but on the order of minutes).

For this reason the pipeline is currently heavily supervised by humans. An analyst goes through each step, running the python code in a Jupyter notebook and upon experiencing problems will make minor code adjustments inline and repeat that section.

In the long run, the goal here is to have zero human intervention. However, in the shorter term we'd like to make this process more seamless. The simplest way to do that seems like it would be to split each section into it's own script, and have a parent script that runs each bit and verifies output. However, we also need the ability to rerun the a file with an identical setup if it fails.

For example:

```
run a --> ✅
run b --> ✅ (b relies on some data produced by a)
run c --> ❌ (c relies on data produced by a and b)
// make some changes to c
run c --> ✅ (c should run in an identical state to its original run)
```

The most obvious way to do this would be to write output from each script to a file, and load all of these scripts into the next one. This would work, but seems a bit inelegant. A database seems another valid option, but a lot of the data doesn't fit cleanly into a db format.

Does anyone have any suggestions for some ways to achieve what I'm looking for? If anything is unclear I'm also more than happy to clarify any points!

Comment: This: http://www.cs.sjsu.edu/~pearce/modules/patterns/distArch/pipeline.htm
or this:                                                             
https://gerardnico.com/data/processing/stream/stream
or this:                                                 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/patterns/pipes-and-filters
or this:                                                
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17305173/how-to-set-up-a-pipeline-using-queues-in-multiprocessing

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could create an object that basically maintains the state after each step and use pickle to serialize that object to a file.

Then it's up to your python script to unpickle that file and then decide which step it needs to start from based on the state.

https://wiki.python.org/moin/UsingPickle

Comment: This is quite an interesting idea, thanks for suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

Queues and pipelines work very nicely with each other (architecturally speaking).  One of the nicer bits is the fact that slower stages can get more workers than faster stages, allowing the pipeline to be optimized based on the workload.

Comment: I'm intrigued by this. Can you expand a little, or point me to a resource where I can read up more?

Comment: This: http://www.cs.sjsu.edu/~pearce/modules/patterns/distArch/pipeline.htm
or this:                                                             
https://gerardnico.com/data/processing/stream/stream
or this:                                                 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/patterns/pipes-and-filters
or this:                                                
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17305173/how-to-set-up-a-pipeline-using-queues-in-multiprocessing